# Match text box to website text box in WP8 App

Tags: c#, vba

So I am a noob at programming and I can give you an example of what I want.

Lets say my app is using my website to access certain elements and I created a username validator which requires a text box and a submit so I was wondering how can I let my users type their request and the website will actually send that request and display the response?

Answer (score 0):

For this, you would need some sort of a database. This is how you could do it. I don't see how this would be done in VB, but in PHP you could do (Assuming you are wanting a log-in system)

```
    public function login($username, $password){
    $users = array(
        array(
            "username" => "Technoash",
            "password" => "34819d7beeabb9qwec854bc8534re44"
        ),
        array(
            "username" => "Monkey",
            "password" => "b82b6fjssafsgfaergafgvsfdbsdbd9"
        )
    );
    foreach($users as $user){
        if(strtolower($user['username'])==strtolower($username)){
            //check log in
            if($user['password']==md5($password)){
                //log in
                $_SESSION['login'] = array(
                    "username" => $user['username'],
                    "rank" => $user['rank']
                );
                return true;
                break;
            }else{
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    //user dosen't exist
    return false;
}
```

This uses an array to store user's details and checks the form input against the array to return a TRUE or FALSE